# jQuery price slider filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have created my jquery price slider but I am not sure how to filter my results so that as you slide you only see the products with that value in range.

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">

<p>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
<ul>
        <li> product - £10 </li>
        <li> product - £50 </li>
        <li> product - £100 </li>
        <li> product - £150 </li>
        <li> product - £200 </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var options = 
        {
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 50, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        };

        $( "#slider-range" ).slider(
            options
        );
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
```

​
My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/uvJ8F/

Comment: yes, this is all being done locally at the moment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would make a few changes:

1. Give your list of products an `id` attribute and give each product a `data-price` attribute that is equal to the price of the item:

   ```
   <ul id="products">
       <li data-price="10"> product - £10 </li>
       <li data-price="50"> product - £50 </li>
       <li data-price="100"> product - £100 </li>
       <li data-price="150"> product - £150 </li>
       <li data-price="200"> product - £200 </li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Add a function that will show or hide those products when a `slide` event occurs:

   ```
   function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
       $("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
           var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
           return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
       }).show();
   }
   ```
3. Call that function from the `slide` event handler:

   ```
   slide: function(event, ui) {
       var min = ui.values[0],
           max = ui.values[1];

       $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);
       showProducts(min, max);
   }
   ```
4. Also call that function right after the slider is initialized so that the correct products are hidden initially:

   ```
   var options = {
      /* snip */
   }, min, max;

   $("#slider-range").slider(options);

   min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
   max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

   $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

   showProducts(min, max);
   ```

The entire snippet:

```
function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
        return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
    }).show();
}

$(function() {
    var options = {
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [50, 300],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var min = ui.values[0],
                max = ui.values[1];

            $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);
            showProducts(min, max);
        }
    }, min, max;

    $("#slider-range").slider(options);

    min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

    $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

    showProducts(min, max);
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5aPg7/

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well. But now I'm trying to create multiple sliders filtering the same list items. Can't get it work from this example.  any ideas?