# Price slider filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, slider

I have a bunch of product images with prices and I'd like to use a price slider to filter which ones are shown. I'm trying to accomplish what is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787027/jquery-price-slider-filter), but using [Ion.RangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) because I'd rather not spend a lot of time customizing the standard jQuery slider UI.

I'm having trouble modifying the jQuery so that using the price slider will actually filter the product images. I know I need to use the onChange method, but I'm at a loss as to how to actually do that.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msmasiello/ddpqaq9j/).

HTML

```
<div class="range-slider">
    <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" />
</div>
<div class="products" id="content">
    <div class="product" data-id="t-shirt-shirt" data-price="158" data-category="shirts b-stevenalan r-stevenalan">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">
                <img src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/StevenAlan/S15_3_MST0113_H401_PD?$redesigngrid$">
            </a>
                <div class="price3"><a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">$158.00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product" data-id="t-shirt-shirt" data-price="300" data-category="shirts b-stevenalan r-stevenalan">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">
                <img src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/StevenAlan/S15_3_MST0113_H401_PD?$redesigngrid$">
            </a>
                <div class="price3"><a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">$300.00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product" data-id="t-shirt-shirt" data-price="5000" data-category="shirts b-stevenalan r-stevenalan">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">
                <img src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/StevenAlan/S15_3_MST0113_H401_PD?$redesigngrid$">
            </a>
                <div class="price3"><a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">$5000.00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>        

     <div class="product" data-id="t-shirt-shirt" data-price="256" data-category="shirts b-stevenalan r-stevenalan">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">
                <img src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/StevenAlan/S15_3_MST0113_H401_PD?$redesigngrid$">
            </a>
                <div class="price3"><a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">$256.00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product" data-id="t-shirt-shirt" data-price="550" data-category="shirts b-stevenalan r-stevenalan">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">
                <img src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/StevenAlan/S15_3_MST0113_H401_PD?$redesigngrid$">
            </a>
                <div class="price3"><a href="http://www.stevenalan.com/840390145802.html#cgid=mens-clothing-shirting&start=0&hitcount=99">$550.00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    from: 0,
    to: 5000
});
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to listen for the onFinish event, iterate over the products and show/hide them

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    from: 0,
    to: 5000,
    onFinish: function (num) {
         $('#content > .product').hide().filter(function() {
            var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
            return price >= num.from && price <= num.to;
        }).show();
    }
});
```